# How to add "Add to Cart" button using Ubercart?

Tags: 8, ubercart

I'm building a website on **Drupal 8** that involves kids videos, that can be sold as separate files. I'm using **Ubercart** module.

I'd like to know how I can put an "Add to cart" button, linking the video content page with the appropriate cart page.

Please put forward your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://www.drupal.org/node/2834032#comment-11846058):

> ... The content type has to be an Ubercart product content type, then the
>   add-to-cart button will automatically show up on that content type
>   along with all the other fields that are necessary for an Ubercart
>   product like price, sku, etc.
>
> To make a content type an Ubercart product content type, edit the
>   content type at /admin/structure/types/manage/{name of content type},
>   choose the "Ubercart product settings" tab in the lower left of the
>   page, select "Content type is a product", then save the content type.